# automated solution for manual copy-paste-transpose?

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that has data pulled from a different data source.

The problem I have is that the data is 'repeated':

*(Site is column A and Owner is Column B):*

```
Site                         Owner
http://website1.com          John Doe
http://website1.com          Jane Doe
http://website2.com          John Smith
http://website2.com          Jane Smith
http://website2.com          John Doe
```

What I would like to change this to is this:

```
Site                         Owner1       Owner 2      Owner 3
http://website1.com          John Doe     Jane Doe
http://website2.com          John Smith   Jane Smith   John Doe
```

I have currently be copying the "Owners" for each site, and pasting them using the "transpose" method in order to accomplish this.  Problem is, there are a LOT of records and this is very boring and probably wasteful work.

Is there a way to accomplish this automatically via macro, script, or otherwise?

Thanks!

Comment: I've done something like that for >100,000 records in excel, but I knew I had some limits in my records. So, I will ask: do you have a maximum number of repeating 'Site'? The process remains quite tedious though, but not as tedious as going through all of them manually.

Comment: Unfortunatley there isn't a 'maximum' number of repeating 'site'.  The data is pulled nightly, and could vary.

Comment: Hmm ok. a macro would be the most efficient solution I guess, in which I'm not too familiar yet...

Comment: Sort by website, add a "Number" column using the formula `=COUNITIF("A$2:A2",A2)` (fill down for all rows). Create a pivot table for your data with website as row label and Number as Column label: use Owner for Value.

Comment: @TimWilliams Do you know of a way to display the names of the owners? I just tried it in Excel-2007 and can't find that option.

Comment: @Kolten - sorry - my mistake: I forgot it's not possible to show non-numeric values in a pivot table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make up for my bad pivot table suggestion above...

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim data, rngTL As Range, num
    Dim i As Long, f As Range
    Dim site, owner

    data = Selection.Value 'select raw data before running

    'where the pivoted data goes: edit to suit...
    Set rngTL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    num = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        site = Trim(data(i, 1))
        owner = Trim(data(i, 2))

        Set f = rngTL.Resize(num + 1, 1).Find(site, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If f Is Nothing Then
            num = num + 1
            rngTL.Offset(num, 0).Value = site
            rngTL.Offset(num, 1).Value = owner
        Else
            f.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = owner
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully!  you just saved me 3 days of mindless work.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I won't write out any VBA for you. But here is how you can accomplish that with some simple worksheet clicking:

You're going to need this custom function from mrickerson on OzGrid:

```
Function ConcatIf(ByVal compareRange As Range, ByVal xCriteria As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal stringsRange As Range, Optional Delimiter As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, criteriaMet As Boolean

    Set compareRange = Application.Intersect(compareRange, _
    compareRange.Parent.UsedRange)

    If compareRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If stringsRange Is Nothing Then Set stringsRange = compareRange
    Set stringsRange = compareRange.Offset(stringsRange.Row - compareRange.Row, _
    stringsRange.Column - compareRange.Column)

    For i = 1 To compareRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To compareRange.Columns.Count
            If (Application.CountIf(compareRange.Cells(i, j), xCriteria) = 1) Then
                ConcatIf = ConcatIf & Delimiter & CStr(stringsRange.Cells(i, j))
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ConcatIf = Mid(ConcatIf, Len(Delimiter) + 1)
End Function
```

Then you are going to need to create a column with your the unique values for your websites.

Then you just need to use the ConcatIf function to create combined column and then you can copy and paste that directly into a text editor ans save it as a CSV:

[image: Example]

If you wanted to automate this I'm sure it would not be difficult for you, but this is generally how you would do it. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion!  I tried it but my knowledge is limited with this aspect of it.  Thanks very much though!

Answer (score -1):

Use Advanced Filter method for unique entries , and copy result to another location using the pastespecial method with transpose.